# Xcode loses connection to iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, core-data

I am developing a program with XCode 10.0. I want to run the program at an older iPad pro which is supported by iOS 9.3.5 only.

When I change in a TabView from one page to another, which loads data from coreDate, the app switches off and I get the following error message:

[image]

I guess the problem has to do with coreData.

With a newer iPad Air2 with iOS 12.0 the programs runs properly.
In both cases the program is the same, compiled for Deployment Target 9.3.

However, the start message in the console is different.
With iPad Air I get the message:

> **CoreData: Inited  (type: SQLite,    url:
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6E295653-1D52-47DF-93B7-7635F02427D2/Library/Application%20Support/DeltaSigmaTestsignalGenerator.sqlite)**

whereas with the older iPad pro the message is:

> **2018-09-25 20:28:11.774 DeltaSigmaTestsignalGenerator[410:85665] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9ED47F2F-C63F-4233-A9A8-6DFF6762D4EF/DeltaSigmaTestsignalGenerator.app/DeltaSigmaTestsignalGenerator.momd/DeltaSigmaTestsignalGenerator.omo'**

Has somebody an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: The path on the second one looks odd ... `model at path ‚/var/...` — notice the comma.

Comment: This was a copy past artefact. It's now corrected.

Comment: "XCode 10.4" There is no such thing as Xcode 10.4.

Comment: Please search before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=failed+to+load+optimized+model